# Spring Integration: JMS loosing messages in case of OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have lost JMS messages(files) which were in the spring integration pipeline flow of **jms:message-driven-channel-adapter** though the adapter is set to transacted mode and custom exception type router with RuntimeException  was configured, which means in case of any Runtime Exception (like PermGenError) it will consume the message, but not happend in my case.

Any help would be appreceated. .

Taking jms messages from ibm mq and after transformation sending it to another queue.

```
<bean id="queueTradeIn" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${queue.name}" />
</bean>

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter concurrent-consumers="1" id="tradeInputQueueAdaptor" destination="queueTradeIn" channel="topLevelErrorHandlerInputChannel" acknowledge="transacted" />
```

Exception Configuration:
I am passing all the messages through **topLevelErrorHandlerInputChannel**.

```
<!-- The ErrorHandler passes the message on the input channel to the output channel. -->
<beans:bean id="topLevelErrorHandler" class="com.xxx.ErrorHandler" >
    <beans:property name="errorChannel" ref="errorChannel"/>
    <beans:property name="outputChannel" ref="dataProcessChain"/>
    <beans:property name="throwablesToHandle" >
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>java.lang.NullPointerException</beans:value>
            <beans:value>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException</beans:value>
            <beans:value>org.dom4j.DocumentException</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.xxx.DLQMessageException</beans:value>
            <beans:value>java.lang.RuntimeException</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<service-activator input-channel="topLevelErrorHandlerInputChannel" ref="topLevelErrorHandler" method="passThrough"/>
<transformer input-channel="errorChannel" method="display" ref="errorMessageConstructor" output-channel="errorLogChannel"/>

<logging-channel-adapter channel="errorLogChannel" id="rejectedLog" expression="'Message passed through!'" level="INFO"/>
```

Comment: You need to show your configuration; you should not lose any messages with a properly configured flow (you should not use `QueueChannel`s in your flow, for example.

Comment: Please see my configuration and I have only Direct channels in my pipeline followed by interceptors.

Comment: Errors are not exceptions.

Comment: @chrylis- yes we are handling the exceptions which are thrown downstream of the message-driven-channel-adapter.

Comment: You need to show the code in `ErrorHandler` together with the configuration downstream of `dataProcessChain` and `errorChannel`. Catching `Throwable` is generally not a good idea; be sure to catch only `Exception`. It is rather unlikely that the framework is causing a memory leak. Use a profiler such as YourKit to analyze your runtime.

Comment: Yeah right @GaryRussell. Application is causing memory leak, previously perm gen size was 64Mb(now increased) but the application wasn't stop when the error occured. It was processing some files on other hand getting error. Need to reproduce the same and check with profiler.

Comment: You should only lose messages if you are catching `Throwable` and consuming `Error`s. If an error is propagated to the container the message will be requeued.

Comment: Actually my _ErrorHandler_ handles exceptions those there are in _throwablesToHandle_ and sets the payload as a exception message. For those which are not there in  _throwablesToHandle_ it rethrows that 'Exception'. So it must be consumed by my error channel, but it wasn't there in my log.